# How do you reference EF in VS 2017 when developing .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I can't see the project.json mentioned in the tutorial in Microsoft website? I thought I just need to put there in it auto-downloads it? Do I use NuGet?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro#entity-framework-core-nuget-packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 no longer uses project.json. Now it's back to using CSPROJ files. The Nuget package for Entity Framework Core is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.